# How often to refresh chain metadata?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I was surprised to see that there while `state_subscribeRuntimeVersion` exists, there's no `chain_subscribeMetadata` so that made me wonder two things:

- What is the expected process for detecting metadata version upgrades? Is it assumed that because it's such a potentially fundamental change, clients will be aware of it in advance and somehow deal with it?
- What are the kinds of processes that a client should invoke when the runtime version changes?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is as follows:

1. Firstly it can't change in the middle of a session so look out for the `session` / `New Session` event.
2. Then the other thing to look for is the `system` / `code updated` event - that will let you know if the next session is going to be using updated metadata.
3. Parachains might well have a different event: `paras` / `CurrentCodeUpdated`.

I've not implemented updating the metadata according to these heuristics yet, but will report back once I have done so as to whether the above was sufficient.

Comment: The chain upgrades are not scheduled based on the sessions - they are scheduled based on the voting periods.

Comment: Interesting. How is a chain code actually deployed? I presume it requires a node restart?